# API URL changes after npm build React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, build, fetch-api

My React App communicates with a backend service using an API endpoint as follows:

```
const API_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL;
const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/data`);
```

The environment variable `REACT_APP_API_URL` is saved in a `.env` file which looks like this:

```
REACT_APP_API_URL="http://1.2.3.4:8000"
```

When I serve the app using `npm start` everything works fine and the developer console shows that the call was made to the right URL:

`Request URL: http://1.2.3.4:8000/data`

I received the data as expected as well. But when I run `npm run build` and then serve the app with `serve -s build/ -l 3000` the app fails to fetch because the request goes to the following URL:

`Request URL: http://localhost:3000/1.2.3.4:8000/`

What am I missing for this to happen?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was not with my React App or the environment variables but with the way I was serving the app

The listening argument `-l` in the `serve` command is the culprit. It should be `-p` for the port to host on

So the right command is

```
serve -s build/ -p 3000
```